# ember cli application build fails: The Broccoli Plugin: [object Object] failed with:

Tags: node.js, ember.js, npm, bower, nvm

```
version: 2.4.2
Could not start watchman; falling back to NodeWatcher for file system events.
Visit http://www.ember-cli.com/user-guide/#watchman for more info.
File: /home/user/Documents/myApp/app
The Broccoli Plugin: [object Object] failed with:
Error: watch /home/user/Documents/myApp/app ENOSPC
at exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
at FSWatcher.start (fs.js:1234:19)
at Object.fs.watch (fs.js:1262:11)
at NodeWatcher.watchdir (/home/user/Documents/myApp/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/sane/src/node_watcher.js:144:20)
at new NodeWatcher (/home/user/Documents/myApp/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/sane/src/node_watcher.js:45:8)
at new sane (/home/user/Documents/myApp/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/sane/index.js:17:12)
at EventEmitter.Watcher_addWatchDir [as addWatchDir] (/home/user/Documents/myApp/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-sane-watcher/index.js:93:17)
at /home/user/Documents/myApp/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/ember-cli-broccoli/lib/builder.js:95:35
at lib$rsvp$$internal$$tryCatch (/home/user/Documents/myApp/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1036:16)
at lib$rsvp$$internal$$invokeCallback (/home/user/Documents/myApp/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1048:17)


The broccoli plugin was instantiated at: 
at WatchedDir.Directory (/home/user/Documents/myApp/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-source/index.js:14:31)
at new WatchedDir (/home/user/Documents/myApp/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-source/index.js:58:13)
at EmberApp._initOptions (/home/user/Documents/myApp/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app.js:221:16)
at new EmberApp (/home/user/Documents/myApp/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app.js:93:8)
at module.exports (/home/user/Documents/myApp/ember-cli-build.js:6:13)
at Class.module.exports.Task.extend.setupBroccoliBuilder (/home/user/Documents/myApp/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/models/builder.js:55:19)
at Class.module.exports.Task.extend.init (/home/user/Documents/myApp/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/models/builder.js:89:10)
at new Class (/home/user/Documents/myApp/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/core-object/core-object.js:18:12)
at Class.module.exports.Task.extend.run (/home/user/Documents/myApp/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/tasks/serve.js:15:19)
at /home/user/Documents/myApp/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/commands/serve.js:70:22
```

Comment: have you tried reinstalling bower components & node modules?

Comment: @stijn.aerts that won't work as this is related with watchman

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you have watchman installed? maybe it could help bypass the Nodewatch problem. In my 64 bit ubuntu:

```
// installing watchman from source
git clone https://github.com/facebook/watchman.git
cd watchman
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

full installation instructions regarding watchman can also be found here https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/install.html

Answer (score 17):

This error is because of inotify watches reaching the maximum limit in your system.

To check the max number of inotify watches:

`cat /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches`

To set max number of inotify watches

Temporarily:

- Run `sudo sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_watches=` with your preferred value at the end.

Permanently:

- `echo 878987 | sudo tee -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches`

Comment: What does setting fs.inotify.max_user_watches do ?

Comment: Is there any **more permanent** way? something which works after reboot?